# Is there a way to make a random range for tags? So certain Objects with that tag destroy

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I am doing a mini game where there are 16 platforms and you have to survive the longest, every round a random colour will pop up and the platforms with that colour will disappear until there is one person left. I was wondering if you could make a random tag selector that will choose a random tag in a list, delete the platforms then remove that tag from the list.
Thanks,
Toby

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @HasanEmrahSüngü I actually am just lost at where to start, I'm still pretty new to Random.Range and stuff, I have looked around for tutorials and haven't found anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can just randomize the index.

```
List<string> Tags = new List<string>();

private void RemoveTag() {

    var RandomTag = Random.Range(0, Tags.Count - 1);
    var Tag = Tags[RandomTag];
    Tags.RemoveAt(RandomTag);
    // Destroy the objects with that tag here

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a class which would do a random selection from given tags.

```
public class RandomColorTagSelector {

    // All possible tags, initialized from constructor
    private readonly List<string> _colorTags;
    // Random selector
    private readonly Random _randomizer = new Random();

    //Create a random color tag selector class
    public RandomColorTagSelector(IEnumerable<string> colortags) {
        _colorTags = colortags.ToList();
    }

    // Gets a random tag from the given tags and removes from the tag pool when it is selected
    public string GetRandomTagAndRemoveItFromRandomList() {
        var randomIndex = _randomizer.Next(0, _colorTags.Count);
        var randomTag = _colorTags[randomIndex];
        _colorTags.RemoveAt(randomIndex);
        return randomTag;
    }
}
```

Comment: HI, I think I understand most of this but .Next and .Toist in undefined do I need a using unityengine. something,